# Switch statement ends prematurely in for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

So I am doing a HackerRank question and cant seem to pass all the tests for some reason. My code passed the first run but appears to fail all the other tests. Looking through debugging, it seems that the for loop terminates once all the switch cases have been used.

This exercise is a Java List problem. An input is given such as

```
5
12 0 1 78 12
2
Insert
5 23
Delete
0
```

The first line contains an integer,N  (the initial number of elements in the list, which is 5 in this case ). 
The second line contains N space-separated integers that make up the list. 
The third line contains an integer,q  (the number of queries). 
The  subsequent lines describe the queries, and each query is described over two lines:

If the first line of a query contains the String **Insert**, then the second line contains two space separated integer, and the value  must be inserted into  at index .
   If the first line of a query contains the String **Delete**, then the second line contains index , whose element must be deleted from .

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ListSolution {
public static void main(String[] args){
    List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
        list1.add(sc.nextInt());
    }

    sc.nextLine();
    int q = sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();
    for(int i=0;i<q;i++){
        switch(sc.nextLine()){
        case "Insert" :
            int x = sc.nextInt();
            int y = sc.nextInt();
            sc.nextLine();
            list1.add(x,y);             
            continue;
        case "Delete" :
            int z = sc.nextInt();
            list1.remove(z);
            continue;
        default:
            continue;
        }
    }
    for(int i=0;i<list1.size(); i++){
        System.out.print(list1.get(i)+" ");;
    }
}
}
```

I was able to finish the problem and pass this specific input. However, it failed all the other in which there were 3 queries in which Insert and Delete are the first two. It seemed that once the switch went through all the cases, it terminated the for loop even though there were more iterations to be done. An example of such input is this:

```
10
100 50 20 10 70 80 200 259 1 900
3
Insert
2 80
Delete
6
Insert
5 89
```

Comment: what would be your desired output? What is your Question?

Comment: What happens if you include `sc.nextLine()` inside the `Delete` case, just like you did for the `Insert` case?

Comment: It would throw an exception. After reading the last number, the input doesn't have a next line. Alternatively to my answer below, he could also put an if condition like if sc.hasNextLine() then sc.nextLine(). Initially the input was not read the right way immediately after the first delete query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the switch case, use sc.next() instead of sc.nextLine(). Finally, delete sc.nextLine() from the insert case.

Comment: It worked! Could you explain how those two edits fixed everything? The reason why I did nextLine is because I thought the scanner would be reading a space after instead of going down to the next line. Is that only applicable if there are more than two things on a line? In other words, if we are only reading one thing in the line, there is no need for nextLine because there is no white space after that one item?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that works:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

class ListSolution {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int i =0;i<n;i++){
            list1.add(sc.nextInt());
        }

        sc.nextLine();
        int q = sc.nextInt();
        sc.nextLine();
        for(int i=0;i<=q;i++){
            String input = sc.nextLine();
            switch(input) {
                case "Insert" :
                    int x = sc.nextInt();
                    int y = sc.nextInt();
                    sc.nextLine();
                    list1.add(x,y);
                    continue;
                case "Delete" :
                    int z = sc.nextInt();
                    list1.remove(z);
                    sc.nextLine();
                    continue;
                default:
                    continue;
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<list1.size(); i++){
            System.out.print(list1.get(i)+" ");;
        }
    }
}
```

The main thing you forgot was that after delete you did not request to get a new line.  So in your second example, the switch was on an empty line return, hence you getting the value wrong.

If I were doing this exercise I would get each line as a String, then parse it.  E.g. for getting to integers:

```
String[] numbers = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
for(String number: numbers){
    list1.add(Integer.valueOf(number));
}
```

This way you do not have the weird end of line confusions.